# ~/.ec2/id_rsa-gsg-keypair not accessible: No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to launch a Hadoop cluster on Amazon ec2, using the instructions in "Hadoop in Action" (also here: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonEC2).

I've set up my private ssh key and configurations, but when I try to launch a cluster using the command-line tools:

```
hadoop-ec2 launch-cluster test-cluster 2
```

I repeatedly get this error:

```
Warning: Identity file ~/.ec2/id_rsa-gsg-keypair not accessible: No such file or directory.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic).
```

The `~/.ec2/id_rsa-gsg-keypair` definitely exists, though, and I did `chmod 600` it:

```
> chmod 600 ~/.ec2/id_rsa-gsg-keypair

> ls -l id_rsa-gsg-keypair
-rw-------  1 my-username
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may have already realized this, but the problem is possibly related to the ~/ path usage. Try using the absolute path /home/username/.ec2